# HP Proliant ML110 G7 Won't Boot from USB

Tags: hp-proliant, proxmox

I have a problem, my HP Proliant ML110 G7 does not want to boot via USB, even though previously there was no problem when installing ubuntu, but now when I want to install proxmox, it seems that the USB is not read when booting. Even tried through manual F11 > 3) USB DriveKey.

[USB Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRXVr.jpg)

[External DriveKey First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/171lM.jpg)

[IPL1: USB DriveKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON3DG.jpg)

Previously, I have installed proxmox also before ubuntu, no problem when booting via usb. I am using rufus 4.4 now

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. ML110 G7 reach end of life 2015.